# import wx.xrc in wxFormBuilder code fails with file not found error

Tags: python, wxpython

The form builder wxFormBuilder imports wx and wx.xrc.  However the second of these causes an error as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peter/python/wxpython/wxFormBuilder/Demo/demo.py", line 4, in 
    import demogui
  File "/home/peter/python/wxpython/wxFormBuilder/Demo/demogui.py", line 11, in 
    import wx.xrc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/wx/xrc.py", line 10, in 
    from ._xrc import *
ImportError: libwx_gtk3u_html-3.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The obvious answer would be that the file was missing, but it isn't:

peter@peter-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ locate libwx_gtk3u_html-3.0.so.0

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/wx/libwx_gtk3u_html-3.0.so.0

So, to my inexperienced eyes it seems to be present and in the right place.  Can anyone make any suggestions on this?

I'm using wxPython for Python 3, by the way.

Many thanks

Comment: How was your wxPython installed? What version and where did it come from?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in wxPython release 4.0.1, see the discussion at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/UBjdeTgOmD4.

The build scripts were setting LD_RUN_PATH only for the wxPython libraries, not for the embedded wxWidgets build.  I can confirm that the fixes mentioned in https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/723 solve the issue.